# unique ptr and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unique-ptr

I have the following question about unique pointers and the ownership transfer
Assume the following

```
class Base
{
    Base()
    {
    }
    void foo(unique_ptr<Base> p)
    {
    }
};
void main()
{
    Base b;
    b.foo(std::unique_ptr<Base> p(new Base);
}
```

The above section of code creates a temporal unique pointer and I expected a compile error. But the code compiles.
I expected the only valid function prototype to be the

```
 void foo(unique_ptr<Base> && p)
```

I am surprize that and the two signatures of the functions are valid.
Could you please explain why the void foo(unique_ptr p) is valid when we pass an rvalue reference?
Thank you

Comment: Code doesn't compile due to mismatched parentheses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` has an rvalue constructor, so you can construct one from an rvalue.  Calling a function that takes a class type as an argument just requires that there be a 1-argument non-explicit constructor for that class<sup>1</sup> that can construct the class type from the parameter supplied to the call.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is not the only way to call such a function; there are other ways involving explicit conversion operators</sub>